# Como compartilhar dados entre vários aplicativos?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Tenho aplicativos **A, B, C** e **D** e preciso compartilhar dados desses apps,  para um app específico **(E)**

***(Basicamente os dados de login, para fazer o login automático. Como o Messenger faz, recuperando os dados de acesso do Facebook)***. 
[image: ao abrir, ele já identifica que estou logado com o facebook e sugere o auto-login]

Desta forma o app **E** apenas vai receber os dados dos outros aplicativos quando solicitado. Já vi e consegui compartilhar dados entre dois aplicativos pelo SharedPreferences recuperando o contexto do package com `createPackageContext`. Porém tenho mais que esses 4 aplicativos, e especificar o contexto de todos apps no aplicativo **E** fica inviável.

Queria saber outra forma de compartilhar esses dados e fazer esse login automático.

Comment: Web Service não ajudaria nesse seu problema?

Comment: @L.Falousk Em tese sim, porém envolveria outros colaboradores da empresa, e estou buscando uma alternativa que não envolva API no momento. Obrigado pela sugestão!

Comment: Content Provider seria o caminho: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html?hl=pt-br